# PHPMyAdmin very slow inserts

Tags: mysql, performance, insert, phpmyadmin, bulk-insert

I was trying to insert around 70K records to mysql database through phpmyadmin and was shocked of how slow it is. It took around 5 hours to complete!

Please find below the details of the table/database:

- I only have access to PHPMyAdmin and FTP. So I cannot use SSH to
  upload the data unfortunately.
- I was only uploading to one table with 8 columns. No foreign keys or computed columns of any kind. Only one auto-increment for the primary key which is not part of the query
- I checked the status tab and no locks or running queries on that table to cause slowliness.
- Some of the values are in Arabic (UTF8)

I tried the following methods to upload the data:

- Separate Insert Queries through SQL tab: Extremely slow and takes 5
  hours. It gave 500 error but it continued to upload the data and didn't stop.
- Joined insert queries through SQL tab [e.g. (record1),(record2),(record3)]: takes long time and suprisingly does not add anything to the database. No errors as well.
- Import Tab: Execution time errors
- Through PHP: Memory was exceeded and do not have access to increase the memory as the server is not under my control

The insert query is simple

```
INSERT INTO mytable (`col1`,`col2`,`col3`,`col4`,`col5`,`col6`,`col7`,`col8`)values(1,100,10,'val1','val2','val3','val4','val5');
```

I would like to upload the data as fast as possible as I only have 5 minutes to provide that data to the customers. Any way to do a bulk insert to be as fast as possible. Alternatives to phpmyadmin that can be added through FTP are welcome as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table is probably ENGINE=InnoDB.  The default is probably to commit a transaction after every INSERT.  You seem to be inserting one row at a time.  Is the input file a list of `INSERTs`?  Where did it come from?  If it came from mysqldump, re run the dump with the option to do multi-row inserts.  If the data is just text, arrange to use `LOAD DATA`.

Can you connect to mysql from another server?  That way you won't be limited to phpmyadmin.  Etc.

Check the Arabic.  Non-English characters cause trouble for a lot of people.  If they are mangled, you *may* need to reload after changing something.

Comment: Thanks. The engine was InnoDB. 
The file comes as an Excel file from a customer and I don't have any control on it. So the fastest way for me is to generate INSERTs per Excel row and submit them through phpmyadmin. I will try the option to convert to CSV and do a LOAD DATA to speed it up.